# NetLogo - move turtle to closest turtle

Tags: netlogo

I am following the principle of a mixture of the "Bank Reserves" Model and of "Move Towards Target Example" Code Example of the Models Library. But instead of moving a person (turtle) to a random bank (turtle), I need the person (turtle) to move to the nearest bank (turtle). Following my attempt of code:

```
if cash >= 100[                      ;; go to the nearest bank for and depose the money for saving
  move-to bank with-min [distance]]] ;; move turtle to closest bank (turtle)
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Please describe the problem. Are you getting an error message (if so, what message and what line), or is it doing something other than what you expected? My guess is that you haven't told it what target to measure the distance to so that it can find the one with the minimum distance.

Comment: @JenB tank you for your comment.
The Idea is, that the turtle called "person" should move to the nearest (in terms of distance) turtle called "bank". My problem is, that I don't know how to code this idea. My first approach is the following: 
```to go
 ask persons [
    if cash >= 100[  ;; go to the nearest bank for saving
      move-to bank with-min [distance]]]```
Please let me know if there are any further uncertainties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move the person (turtle) to the nearest bank (turtle) I used the following line of code:

```
to go
  ask persons [
    set cash cash - 3 ;; removes 3$ within each tick
    set label cash    ;; renews the label
    if cash <= 0[
      move-to min-one-of other banks [distance myself] ;; moves to the closest bank
    ]
  ]
```

`min-one-of` and `myself` were keywords to this solution.

Answer (score 0):

The NetLogo dictionary entry for `distance` is a very similar problem to yours - in that case finding the turtle that is furthest away. You haven't told `distance` what to find the distance to, the asking turtle. Try this:

```
move-to min-one-of banks [distance myself]
```

However, I would have thought that the way you coded it should have generated an error message so I am not sure if there is another problem elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now after inserting the keyword "myself" which makes sens in my opinion I receive the following error message: `BANK expected 1 input, a number` 
I assume netlogo requires an exact turtle  to measure the distance. But I would like to have the closest one. Do you think there is a possibility for this?

Comment: see update. you could use `one-of` but there is a primitive `min-one-of` that does it all together